# Bash Variable inside sql query. CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I have a shell script where insert data from a file into hive table via impala.

```
#declare variables
YEAR=$(date +"%Y")
MONTH=$(date +"%-m")
DAY=$(date +"%-d") 
.....

$IMPALA_CONNECTION -q "LOAD DATA INPATH '$HDFS_DIR/text_file.txt' INTO TABLE db.tbl_stg;
INSERT INTO db.tbl PARTITION(year, month, day) SELECT rest, of, sql, $YEAR, $MONTH, $DAY FROM 
db.tbl_stg;
```

ERROR: ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:
..., 2023, 5, 9  FROM db.tbl_stg...
^
For some reason it does not like $DAY variable because if I hardcode 9, it works perfectly.

This is if I echo the query:

```
impala-shell -k --ssl -i pserver:21000 --ca_cert=path_to_cert.pem -q 
LOAD DATA INPATH '$hdfs_path_here/impala_query_hist.txt' INTO TABLE 
db.tbl_stg;

INSERT INTO db.tbl PARTITION(year, month, day) SELECT ......, ...., 
memory_accrual, ddl_type, rows_inserted, hdfs_bytes_written, 2023, 5, 9  
FROM db.tbl_stg;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please echo the query and show the result.

Comment: @Barmar this is Hadoop. Hive table

Comment: What is the `...` stuff? You're getting an error from the query, it doesn't help if you hide part of it.

Comment: @Barmar this is a huge query and it contains personal data that I cant expose. The main thing is that if I hardcode $DAY variable it works just fine

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would make a difference whether you hard-code the `9` or it comes from `$DAY`. The query is the same.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any hidden characters in the `DAY` assignment. Use a hex editor to examine the file.

Comment: You can check the exact contents of the variable with `printf '%s' "$DAY" | xxd`. Also, putting `set -x` before the problem command might clarify what's actually getting executed (but a warning: it tends to use weird quoting conventions; it looks like you have single-quotes in the query, so it'll probably display it as a single-quoted string with `'\''` where the embedded quotes are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helpful comments. There was an extra space at the end of the variable DAY=$(date +"%-d") . You can see it if you highlight that light in my original question post. After removing the extra space everything is worked